# Lenovo B50-80 No sound at all

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa

I installed Ubuntu and sound not working. I already tried every question on stack exchange and all over internet. I'm using Lenovo B50-80 with intel corporation broadwell-u audio controller. I can't hear external or internal audio outputs.Apparently, my sound card is not recognized by ubuntu and dummy output is used. For some reason I have always 0 modules loaded.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Please, anyone, help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I'm awesome all by myself.
I decided to try [official sound troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) once again. Like before, I was stuck on step 3, I was unable to perform `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra- uname -r` because package `linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic` was not found in any repository. I gone to web and downloaded .deb what was installed using `sudo dpkg -i`

After some tweaking to make output come from my 3.5 mm audio jack it works fine.